# Amazon.IonDotnet.Internals.Text.InvalidTokenException error while reading stream data from AWS Kinesis by QLDB stream

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-qldb

I have a running solution doing some operation on AWS QLDB. All workloads are developed with .NET. So far no problem...

Now I am just trying to stream QLDB data. The data in QLDB is streamed with AWS Kinesis as a built-in feature of QLDB.

I am trying to read the data from Kinesis Stream with .NET SDKs.

While I read data stream,

```cs
IonLoader.Default.Load(record.Data)
```

I get the following error

```
Amazon.IonDotnet.Internals.Text.InvalidTokenException: Token � : 65533 is not expected
```

I got this error randomly...Not sure about the root cause.

When I check the stream data in Kinesis, I noticed this strange pattern.
And I am pretty sure that errors are for those data.

Any suggestion would be great?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have Kinesis record aggregation enabled [as it's enabled by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/streams.create.html) for QLDB streams.

This [short documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-deaggregation.html) links out to an AWS labs implementation for a few languages: https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation. C# is not implemented, so you would either have to implement a C# deaggregator yourself or turn off record aggregation for your stream in the QLDB console.

Comment: Thanks a lot...This seems to be the root cause. I did some tests with record aggregation disabled and no error so far. I will continue with some tests.